# "Selector name found in current argument registers:", What does it mean?

Tags: ios, crash-reports, segmentation-fault, hockeyapp

I am monitoring my App using HockeyApp, I can see the following CrashGroups in my HockeyApp Panel.

**Crash Group**:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x20

Crashed Thread:  0

main "Selector name found in current argument registers: release"

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib    0x0000000182d9c160 objc_release + 16
1   libobjc.A.dylib    0x0000000182d9dae8 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 504
2   CoreFoundation     0x00000001835fc9fc _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
3   Foundation         0x00000001840141c0 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 148
4   CoreData           0x000000018561c8d0 -[NSManagedObjectContext _mergeChangesFromDidSaveDictionary:usingObjectIDs:] + 3000
5   CoreData           0x000000018561cc20 -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] + 496
6   Foundation         0x00000001840f402c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 336
7   CoreFoundation     0x00000001836d509c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION + 20
8   CoreFoundation     0x00000001836d4b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 536
9   CoreFoundation     0x00000001836d2830 __CFRunLoopRun + 720
10  CoreFoundation     0x00000001835fcc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 380
11  GraphicsServices   0x0000000184ee4088 GSEventRunModal + 176
12  UIKit              0x00000001888e6088 UIApplicationMain + 200
13  Essentials         0x000000010004d964 main (main.m:52)
14  ???                0x000000018319a8b8 0x0 + 0
```

**Other similar crash groups are given below.**

**Crash Group 1**:

```
main  "SIGSEGV - Selector name found in current argument registers: count"
```

**Crash Group 2**:

```
main "SIGSEGV - Selector name found in current argument registers: autorelease"
```

**Crash Group 3**:

```
main "SIGSEGV - Selector name found in current argument registers: retain"
```

HockeyApp didn't give enough clue to identify the reason. Not stack trace information as well, since all these crashes are happening in main thread.

`Selector name found in current argument registers`? What does it mean? Can someone give an example for this crash.

The number of occurrences of these crash types are keep on increasing in iOS 10.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22249665/4611751

Comment: Is this crash have any relation with Core Data?

Comment: The reason for the crash is, It was trying to do release on an invalid object which already released.  Please check memory management on your code.

Comment: My App complies ARC.

Comment: ARC doesn't mean you don't have to think about memory management! Especially when using dispatch queues and blocks you HAVE to think about memory management.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selector name found in current argument registers: isEqual:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22095183/selector-name-found-in-current-argument-registers-isequal)